# Layout constraints not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint

I am having a lot of trouble getting this second custom class, which is another UICollectionView (green background) constraining to the bottom of the class above. I've tried all different sorts of constraints and constants of "0" etc. However it keeps positioning it on top of the other class. Does anyone have any ideas about what is happening?

Here is the screenshot: [image]

```
class JobCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout   {

private let cellId = "jobCellId"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()

}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let jobLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .green
    label.text = "I WANT TO"
    label.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 149, green: 149, blue: 149)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 16)
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let jobsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return collectionView
}()

func setupViews() {

    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    jobsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    jobsCollectionView.delegate = self
    jobsCollectionView.register(JobSingleCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


    addSubview(jobLabel)
    addSubview(jobsCollectionView)

    jobLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    jobLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    jobLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width).isActive = true
    jobLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true



    jobsCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: jobLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    jobsCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    jobsCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    jobsCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.height).isActive = true

}
```

Here is the second blue cell:

```
class DayCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

private let dayCellId = "dayCellId"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()

}

let daysCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return collectionView
}()

let dayLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .green
    label.text = "WHEN"
    label.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 149, green: 149, blue: 149)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 16)
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

func setupViews() {

    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


    addSubview(dayLabel)

    dayLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    dayLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    dayLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    dayLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: So you have DayCell overlapping to other view. Did you check that DayCell and JobCell and other are subViews of the same view?

Comment: The green and red are under the same subview. However the DayCell (blue) that is overlapping, is under another class, so under different setupViews() function, subview.. 
Is this an issue?

Comment: If you trying to layout blueView to red view than yes. Constraints can be effectively applied to the views of the save hierarchy level

Comment: Ahh ok thanks very much. How would you go about setting up the layouts then? Considering I have to combine the setupView() functions within different classes.

Comment: UICollectionView cannot size itself as well as the problem with the cell which should not have any constraints to other views. You will need to get a count of your data and update a fixed height constraint based on that to give your collectionView a height